# How to retrieve the data from Firebase Database inside muti-layer multiple child nodes?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Snap of my database]

I have been trying to retrieve the data from Firebase Database but unable to find a way with this type of data structure. As you can see in the AllStores node, there are multiple stores and each store has its own data with own products and the products have many main categories and each main category has multiple sub category , sub- categories have multiple brands and finally each brand has multiple products with a random number as its node. I know this structure is a bit complicated and i can get the data by separating the nodes and create again and again which is a bit tedious. So, is the any possible way of retrieving the whole store with all of its data in an single object and put it on a list or do i have to manually put the path by just retrieving the store data and use reference.child("") method to get each and every data. If i find a way of retrieving this data structure without changing its nodes , it will be of great ease to me . Any answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> is the any possible way of retrieving the whole store with all of its data in an single object

Yes, this is already what happens when you fetch a node from Realtime Database.  When you get [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) for any given node, it will contain all of the child nodes inside it.  All you have to do is use [child()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#child(java.lang.String)) on that snapshot to dig into each of the child nodes to get a new DataSnapshot with all of the child data.  Keep digging in to each child the same way.  Everything child will be nested inside other DataSnapshots.

So, if you have a DataSnapshot of "/AllStores/Mazbat Store", you can go down as far as you need to find a snapshot with the data you want.

```java
DataSnapshot store = // fetch of "/AllStores/Mazbat Store"
DataSnapshot item = store.child("Store Products").child("Electronics").child("Camera").child("Asus").("6432649")
```

You will obviously have to write a lot of code to get a hold of everything from the top level snapshot, but it will all be there.

Comment: Thanks , but i know that , the problem is i have multiple store and i want to retrieve each store using a class, snapshot.getValue("The class for retrieving the whole store object") and retrieve all the stores and put it in a list like List<StoreClass> and use it whenever necessary. I just cant think of a class that would help me retrieve all of the data at once.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I just can't think of a class".  In any event, you're going to have to write some data to extra all the child data and do something with it.  It's up to you to decide what to do.

Comment: Can't i retrieve the whole Mazbat Store as an Object using HashMap or Lists, without going store.child("Store Products").child("Electronics").child("Camera").child("Asus").("6432649") because i want to display each store in a recycler view to thousands of user and once the user clicks on the store i have to show al the store data accordingly. If there are no other way , then i will have to use the way as you mentioned earlier

Comment: I suggest looking over the API documentation for DataSnapshot to see what it can give you.  You could use getValue() to get a Map. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#doc

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to use a map , i am just unable to set up a HashMap that fits the database structure. Anyways , thanks for your help.